# Why typeorm does not bring the all fields when using findOneBy method to take all the maching results?

Tags: postgresql, backend, typeorm

I have a postgress database,that I store some fields as a jsonB format. When I query the database, it brings me the matching rows buts some fields are empty

see here how I query the database

```js
const url = await this.paymentRepository.findOneBy({
      reference: 'fe07fb3c-eed8-4fa1-bb63-9f5a482be328',
    });
```

I got this as a response succesfully

```js
url Payment {
  id: 'c2202f25-b639-4254-8929-b4466bdffaea',
  createdAt: 2023-06-15T08:23:17.305Z,
  updatedAt: 2023-06-15T08:25:21.099Z,
  reference: 'fe07fb3c-eed8-4fa1-bb63-9f5a482be328',
  email: 'sayinmehmet47@gmail.com',
  callback: 'http://localhost:3103/api/fact-sheet-sales/complete',
  callbackReference: 'ae2e555c-966e-4b6f-aefc-addb3e6837de',
  amount: 2900,
  paid: true,
  transactionId: '',
  transactionUuid: '',
  invoiceId: '10259707',
  payment: {}
}
```

but see here **payment** is already in my database,
[image]

why all the fields come from query except payment not come ?